# Get specific information from Wikipedia Information Box

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm trying to get the details of the latest release in the information box on the right side. I'm trying to retrieve "`6.2 (Build 9200) / August 1, 2012; 7 years ago`" from the box by scraping [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2012) using jsoup.

I have code that pulls all data from the box but I can't figure out how to pull the specific part of the box.

```java
org.jsoup.Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2012").execute();
String html = res.body();
Document doc2 = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);
Element body = doc2.body();
Elements tables = body.getElementsByTag("table");
for (Element table : tables) {
    if (table.className().contains("infobox")==true) {
        System.out.println(table.outerHtml());
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query for the table row that contains a link that *ends* with `Software_release_life_cycle`:

```
String url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2012";
try {
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Elements elements = document.select("tr:has([href$=Software_release_life_cycle])");
    for (Element element: elements){
        System.out.println(element.text());
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    //exception handling
}
```

This is why, by looking at the full html, I found out that the row you need (*and **only** the row you need -this is a vital detail!-*) is formed like this. Infact `elements` will actually contain only an `Element`.

Finally you extract only the text. This code will print:

```
Latest release 6.2 (Build 9200) / August 1, 2012; 7 years ago (2012-08-01)[2]
```

If you need even more refinement you can always `substring` it.

Hope I helped!

( [selector syntax reference](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) )